# How can i make my horizontal stepper show?

Tags: flutter

How can I make my horizontal stepper show? I am trying to put a horizontal stepper under the divider; however, it does not show. I tried everything, and nothing seems to work right now. The stepper shows when I change it to a vertical stepper; however, I do not want to use a vertical stepper. Can someone please help me? This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  List<Step> getSteps() => [
        Step(
            isActive: currentStep >= 0,
            title: const Text('Personal'),
            content: Container()),
        Step(
          isActive: currentStep >= 1,
          title: const Text('Company'),
          content: Container(),
        ),
        Step(
          isActive: currentStep >= 2,
          title: const Text('Complete'),
          content: Container(),
        )
      ];

  int currentStep = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20, 20.0, 0.0),
                    child: RichText(
                      text: const TextSpan(
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'Test',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "La Belle Aurore",
                              fontSize: 40,
                              color: Color(0xFFFFE381),
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'App',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Inter',
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Test',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 107, 107),
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text(
                    'Create an Account',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Divider(
                    thickness: 2,
                    indent: 16,
                    endIndent: 16,
                  ),
                  Stepper(
                    type: StepperType.vertical,
                    currentStep: currentStep,
                    onStepTapped: (step) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentStep = step;
                      });
                    },
                    steps: getSteps(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for horizontal you have to define the bounds of the stepper

```
SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5, //For example scale height to half of screen
    //height: 500, //For example if you want to define a static height
    child: Stepper(
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
        currentStep: currentStep,
        onStepTapped: (step) {
            setState(() {
                currentStep = step;
            });
        },
        steps: getSteps(),
    ),
),
```